# x86 - Switching from 32-bit to 64-bit via RETF

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, memory-segmentation

I was looking at some anti-disassembler techniques and came across the following snippet:

```
push 0x33
call $+5
add  [esp+0x10+var_10], 5
retf
; next instruction here
```

So in a nutshell, this would immediately jump to the instruction right after `RETF`, but would mess up 32-bit disassemblers. Still not clear to me why that is though.

Now, I've been told that `RETF` returns to a 64-bit segment, and hence debugging this on a 32-bit debugger produces the wrong disassembly. When running this snippet on a 64-bit debugger (in my case windbg) it produces the correct result.

My question here is: **Is there anything special about the `push 0x33`? Is 0x33 some kind of special value?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`retf` itself doesn't mean "return to a 64-bit segment". It means "return to the specified segment and address", as opposed to near `ret` meaning "return to the specified address without changing segments". The `0x33` is the segment to return to, which happens to be the segment that's used for 64-bit code. (`0x23` is the 32-bit segment.)

Comment: Note that the segment numbers depend on OS and some times OS version.